# Functional Programming approach for Queue pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, functional-programming, f#-3.0

Can a queue handling async operations be implemented under the principles of [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)? It's an AsyncQueue basically.

```
var list = [];
var inProgress = false;

function Queue() {}

Queue.prototype.enqueue = function(data) {
    list.push(data);
    if(!inProgress) {
         inProgress = true;
         start(list.shift());
    }
}

function start(data) {
    // initiate some async activity, and call dequeue on completion
}

function dequeue() {
    if(list.length) {
       start(list.shift());
    } else {
       isProgress = false;
    }
}
```

Evidently there's some kind of state getting managed, both with the `list` and `inProgress`, not sure how can this be converted into it's Functional Programming equivalent. F# code also welcome.

Javascript Promise based approach also welcome. Note: list is not a fixed size and items get dynamically pushed inside at random.

Comment: please explain how it's not thread-safe

Comment: I'm not clear though, but it runs in node.js (single threaded) and Queue is a single object within runtime, the next task will only run if first one finishes

Comment: For some reason my tired brain have read that code as schematic C#, as long as you mentioned F#, but not JS, sorry.

Comment: never mind, so we can't get rid of managing state in here, right?

Comment: I'm not an expert on functional programming, but I think the idea of a queue is more of a procedural construct. Perhaps what you are looking to implement is a stream?

Comment: @etherealite not at all: functionally you consume a head of the queue and pass further its tail. It's a very common pattern (so common so that there are `head` + `tail` terms designed for it).

Comment: @etherealite any example for stream pattern for analysis please?